# Does Sphinx realtime index, support multi-threaded search, yet? What if they are part of a distributed index?

Tags: multithreading, indexing, full-text-search, sphinx

Question is related to sphinx real time(rt) indexes. 
I have a distributed index that contains three rt indexes. Each rt index has about 21 million docs per rt index (total 3 * 21 =  63 million).

I am trying to improve performance of this index configuration, and came across this informative post:

> As of this moment, the RT index will use only one core per search, no
>   matter how many disk chunks it has (this may change in the future!).

*Source* http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2014/02/12/rt_performance_basics/comment-page-1/ (Link dated 2014)

Does the above statement mean that the above configuration for the indexes will always run in a single threaded manner per search, so if I have three rt indexes in a distributed index, on a four core machine, only three searches can be done simultaneously, which will then be distributed on three cores by the distributed index?

[sphinx](/questions/tagged/sphinx) [fulltext](/questions/tagged/fulltext) [indexing](/questions/tagged/indexing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distributed index should run each component index in a new thread, but each RT index will be singled threaded.

... so it could use 3 cores to run the query (one RT index per core)

But, note the mapping of threads to cores is NOT absolute. That's up to the OS. The three 'threads' could end up being run on one core. 
... also sphinx isnt restricted to just running as many threads as there are cores. It may spawn more threads, which compete for cores.

Comment: Does this mean rt indexes are not suitable for my case ? How can I gain performance. Right now each of my query with a keyword that was not searched before (un-cached) takes about  10 seconds to just count(*) the number of records. I have about 3000 ram chunks / rt index, which according to the article could be a cause of performance degradation, I am trying to fix that issue. But will this change anything assuming I would be able to parallelize only 3 search or as you said none!! *tears rolling down*

Comment: Well for a start dont use count() - that is very inefficient! Run a query and can also get the number of records is in SHOW META. If you really want to get a count without actual documents, use LIMIT 0.